# wxpython text editor status bar update

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I am using wxpython for Python 2.7. I am working on a text editor, but have encountered a problem with the status bar.

I want my status bar to have `Line xx, Column xx`. However, I have only found a way to update it using a key press, for when the user is typing. I also want the user to be able to click around and see their cursor position within the text editor. I have tried `self.control.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.UpdateLineCol)`. When I run this, it seems to have rebound the left mouse button, so I can't click around.

My UpdateLineCol code is as follows:

```
def UpdateLineCol(self, e):
    line = self.control.GetCurrentLine() + 1
    col = self.control.GetColumn(self.control.GetCurrentPos())
    stat = 'Line %s, Column %s' % (line, col)
    self.StatusBar.SetStatusText(stat, 0)
```

How can I bind the left mouse button to update the status bar but also let me click around with the cursor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call event.Skip() to allow normal processing to happen after your function.

```
def UpdateLineCol(self, e):
    line = self.control.GetCurrentLine() + 1
    col = self.control.GetColumn(self.control.GetCurrentPos())
    stat = 'Line %s, Column %s' % (line, col)
    self.StatusBar.SetStatusText(stat, 0)
    e.Skip()
```

See: https://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.MouseEvent-class.html

> EVT_LEFT_DOWN Left mouse button down event. The handler of this event should normally call event.Skip() to allow the default processing to take place as otherwise the window under mouse wouldn't get the focus.

edit:
Your traceback:

```
  File "editor.py", line 211, in <module>
    frame = MainWindow(None, 'Avix')
  File "editor.py", line 103, in __init__
    self.UpdateLineCol(self)
  File "editor.py", line 208, in UpdateLineCol
    e.Skip()
  AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'Skip'
```

specifies `self.UpdateLineCol(self)` what happened to `self.UpdateLineCol(self,e)`
You are calling this function without the event as a parameter.

Comment: I tried this and it gave me an error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "editor.py", line 211, in <module>
    frame = MainWindow(None, 'Avix')
  File "editor.py", line 103, in __init__
    self.UpdateLineCol(self)
  File "editor.py", line 208, in UpdateLineCol

    e.Skip()
AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'Skip'`

Comment: As far as I am aware all events have the attribute `Skip`, I can only assume that you are calling `UpdateLineCol` in another manner, not just with the `Bind` command

Comment: I am also calling it with `self.control.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_UP, self.UpdateLineCol)` and `self.UpdateLineCol(self)` to update it when the editor starts. How can I make skip work? All the code is in my GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/thatpotato/Avix-Editor)

Comment: Define another function for the startup is the least complicated method that springs to mind.

Comment: How would I do that? I'm very new to wxpython.

Comment: Never mind. Thank you! I figured out how. I just created a startup function without `e.Skip()` in it.

Comment: Use the other (non-event) function after things like `cut` and `paste` to update the status bar